# PHP I'm trying to split a string of Lat Lng Waypoints, whats the best method to use

Tags: php, split

I am using the google maps api to return a string of waypoint Lat/Lng values.
and example of this is:

```
(51.4409138, -2.542236799999955),(51.44766809999999, -2.544380100000012),(51.4355129, -2.5526174999999967)
```

My target is to result in something like this:

```
array (
   0 => array (0 => 51.4409138,1 => -2.542236799999955),
   1 => array (0 => 51.44766809999999,1 => -2.544380100000012),
   2 => array (0 => 51.4355129,1 => -2.5526174999999967)
)
```

What can you suggest is the best method to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$first = explode('),(', $coords);
foreach ($first as $result) {
    $second[] = explode(', ', trim($result, '()`');
}
```

`$second` is what you need.

For your interest, here is a one-liner (5.3):

```
$desired_output = array_map(function($pair) {
                               return explode(', ', trim($pair, '()`');
                            }, explode('),(', $original_string));
```

Comment: Hmm i thought they might of been a easier method to use like preg_split with a certain expression but I guess explode works just fine.

Comment: Yes, perhaps. But this one is more straightforward.